# Call function from another class to draw on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm implementing a calendar function in an app. When the calendar class Calendar.m will appear I call a function to start another function (CalendarArrayHandler.m) that will handle the parsing with the following code:

```
CalendarArrayHandler *caller = [[CalendarArrayHandler alloc] init];

[caller performSelectorInBackground:@selector(mergeCalendars:) withObject:calendarUrlArray];
```

The CalendarArrayHandler.m-class then initiate the parsing and a lot of other stuff to interpret the XML-file. When it's done I save an NSMutableArray with the following code:

```
NSData *calendarData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:sortedArrayToSave];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:calendarData forKey:@"CalendarEntries.dat"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *arrayFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CalendarEntries.dat"];

[calendarData writeToFile:arrayFileName atomically:YES];
```

At this point I call the loadCalendarEntriesFromFile-function in the Calendar.m class with

```
Calendar *caller = [[Calendar alloc] init];

[caller performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadCalendarEntriesFromFile) withObject:nil];
```

This function (now in the Calendar.m-class) receives the NSMutableArray (successfully) which will be drawn on the screen in the displayCalendar-function. This function is called with

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayCalendar) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

It's here something goes wrong, the UIviews and labels will not be displayed on the screen. I tried calling the displayCalendar-function with an IBAction and it works just fine, but I can't get it to work when i call the load function from outside the Calendar.m-class even though the displayCalendar-function is called with the performSelectorOnMainThread-function.

I hope that you can understand my problem and see why it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by from outside the Calendar.m class? From your description it seems like you're in the Calendar.m class. If not, then don't send performSelector message to 'self'.

Comment: I call the loadCalendarEntriesFromFile-function (that is in Calendar.m) from the CalendarArrayHandler.m-class. The loadCalendarEntriesFromFile-function then calls displayCalendar.